# Typescript compiler - Include .d.ts file from node_modules folder

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, webdriver-io

After adding `webdriverio` to a typescript project, all kinds of errors like this appear during transpilation:

```
error TS2694: Namespace 'global.WebdriverIO' has no exported member 'Element'.

221 export interface ElementBase extends InstanceBase, ElementReference, CustomInstanceCommands<WebdriverIO.Element> {
```

I see in the [webdriverio docs](https://webdriver.io/docs/typescript/) that some types files need to be added to tsconfig like so:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "types": ["node", "webdriverio/async"]
    }
}
```

However, this causes typescript to ignore everything that's in the `node_modules/@types` folder (besides, I believe, `@types/node`). Looking at `node_modules/webdriverio/async.d.ts`, I can see that the namespace `WebdriverIO` is in there.

How can `webdriverio/async.d.ts` to typescript transpilation without ignoring all of those essential types?